# Gradle: How to filter and search through text?

Tags: string, text, groovy, gradle, filter

I'm fairly new to gradle. How do I filter text in the following manner?
Pretend that the output/result I want to filter will be the two URLs below.

```
"http://localhost/artifactory/appNameIwant/moreStuffHereThatsDynamic" 
> I want this URL 

"http://localhost/artifactory/differentAppName"
> I don't want this URL
```

I want to put up a "match" variable that would be something like
variable = http://localhost/artifactory/appnameIwant

So essentially, the string will not be a perfect match. I want it to filter and provide back any URLs that start with the variable listed above. It cannot be a perfect match as the characters after the /appnameIwant/ will be changing.

I want to use a for loop to cycle through an array, with an if then statement to return any matches. For instance.

```
for (i=0; i < results.length; i++){
if (results[i] strings matches  (http://localhost/artifactory/appnameIwant) {
return results[i] }
```

I am just filtering the URL strings themselves, not anything complicated inside the webpages.

Let me know if further explanation would be helpful.

Thanks so much for your time and help!

Comment: Could you please provide some context around what you're building with Gradle? Is this a Grails app or Servlets or something else?

Maybe you could post part of your build.gradle file

Comment: Sure. I'm going to completely edit my main post - should be good in 5 minutes or so, thanks!

Comment: Edited, let me know if you need further  clarification.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out - I just used

```
if (string.startsWith"texthere")) {println string}
```

A lot easier than I thought!